# Why my router alows to connect to the internet only after plugging the cord to laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet, router

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.
I have D-link dir-320 wireless router.

When I turn on my laptop Lenovo G555, I'm trying to connect to router by it's usually unsuccessful.
But if I'll pull the ethernet cord from the router and insert it into my laptop, everything will work well.
**And if after that I'll pull the ethernet cord from the laptop and insert it into the router, my laptop connects to the router and it will have Internet access via wifi.**


How to make the laptop directly connects to the Internet after booting without switching the cord?